# Authenticate chrome extension with Django backend

Tags: javascript, django, web-services, google-chrome-extension, django-authentication

I currently have a backend written in Django and a chrome extension which makes rest requests to the backend. The backend is set up for user registration and login through a webpage.

I'd like to authenticate users in the chrome extension such that they can login once and the chrome extension will maintain the session across multiple loads on different pages. All rest requests from the extension should then be authenticated with the ability to tell which user is making a given request in the handler for the request.

I am **very** unfamiliar with this type client-server authentication and after a look around it looks like oauth or simple https header authentication may be the way to go. I am uncertain about oauth as this seems overkill (and I am generally unfamiliar with it), while I'm not sure how to maintain the https authentication across uses of the extension. Could someone sketch out the necessary elements from the Django backend through to making the login and subsequent rest requests in javascript?